# Advise on exercise with scala abstract types

Tags: scala, abstract-type

I'm looking for an advise on this exercise I'm doing - specifically, what areas can be improved/shortened? I don't like that to feed the animals I have to use **asInstanceOf** but cannot find a better way. An idea is that I need to run this function for millions of objects so performance is important.

P.S. Would generics perform better in my case?

```
trait Animal {
  type suitableFood
  def eat(f: suitableFood)
}
trait Food
case class Grass (val color: String) extends Food
case class Fish (val size: String, val condition: String) extends Food

trait GrassT{
  type suitableFood = Grass
}
trait FishT{
  type suitableFood = Fish
}
class Cow extends Animal with GrassT{
  def eat (f: suitableFood) = {
    println("moo " + f.color)
  }
}
class Sheep extends Animal with GrassT{
  def eat (f: suitableFood) = {
    println("baaa " + f.color)
  }
}
class Cat extends Animal with FishT{
  def eat (f: suitableFood) = {
    println("mew " + f.size + " " + f.condition)
  }
}
val cow = new Cow
val sheep = new Sheep
val whiteCat = new Cat
val blackCat = new Cat
val fish = new Fish("small", "fresh")
val grass = new Grass("green")
val cats = List(whiteCat, blackCat)
val farmAnimals = List(sheep, cow)
def feedAnimals[F <: Food](food: F, animals: List[Animal]) = {
  animals.foreach(a => a.eat(food.asInstanceOf[a.suitableFood]))
}
feedAnimals(grass, farmAnimals)
feedAnimals(fish, cats)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put a stricter type restriction on `feedAnimals`:

```
def feedAnimals[F <: Food](food: F, animals: List[Animal { type suitableFood = F }]) = 
    animals.foreach(_.eat(food))
```

Or:

```
def feedAnimals[F <: Food, A <: Animal { type suitableFood = F }](food: F, animals: List[A]) = 
    animals.foreach(_.eat(food))
```

Unlike the solution using `asInstanceOf`, these solutions will fail at compile time (as opposed to runtime) for statements like `feedAnimals(grass, cats)`, as desired.

Generics might be simpler in this case, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was after!